# TYPO3. Extension tx_news. Custom fields in the searchForm news template

Tags: search, typo3, tx-news

TYPO3. In the tx_news extension of the news search form there are filter fields - minimum and maximum date. How to create your own filter fields – year and category – to find news by year and category?
Thank you.

Comment: You need to extend the Controller responsible for the filter  & if needed the Repository for the news.